# @ in Regular Expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

I created the register form in asp.net. And I want to validate Name. This is not included special characters especially '@' character. I used a regular expression validator. I wrote in ValidationExpression that is ^[A-Za-z0-9.'-_\s]+$. It is OK special characters exact '@' character. How to correct regexp. Please help me.

Comment: can you explain more? did't understand what you meant by "it is OK special characters exact '@' character. How to correct regexp. Please help me." what did you mean by correct it?

Comment: sorry for my English, I mean that I was using this regular expression (regexp), this can catch special character but cannot catch '@' character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'-_` means every character between `'` and `_`, which includes a large number of characters.

You should escape the `-` by writing `\-`.

Comment: ...or move the `-` to the very end: `^[A-Za-z0-9.'_\s-]+$`